# Typescript interface implementation with static variable

Tags: typescript

This is from the [sidewaffle template](http://sidewaffle.com/)

```
interface Ifactory1 {
        greeting: string;
        serviceId: string;
        changeGreeting: () => void;
    }

    class factory1 implements Ifactory1 {
        static serviceId: string = "factory1";
        greeting = "Hello";

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        }

        changeGreeting() {
            this.greeting = "Bye";
        }
    }

    app1.factory(factory1.serviceId, ['$http', '$resource', ($http, $resource) =>
        new factory1($http, $resource)
    ]);
```

I get the error:

```
Error   27  Class factory1 declares interface Ifactory1 but does not implement it:
    Type 'factory1' is missing property 'serviceId' from type 'Ifactory1'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Static members are not accessible from instances of the class. You need an instance member to fulfill the interface.